# how to create debian package using make all

Tags: makefile, deb, debian-packaging

I know how to create a .deb package with simple project using `dpkg --build project` in structure

```
( project ( bin (source files), debian (controlfile) ))
```

but in case of complete project with Makefiles, can't copy the project bin folder.

what to add in makefile so project gets builds also create .deb package with "make" command?

where to store DEBIAN directory with control file?

Comment: debian directory should be placed on the top directory of the sources. Then in your makefile you call the dpkg-buildpackage as you will do normally (or similar tools). Debian has a "short" new maintainer guide which explain the basic of packaging. You should read it. Then in your makefile you just call the command you normally write on terminal.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72754093/create-debian-package-without-bin-dir-inside-project      @giacomo-catenazzi can you please share ur views on mentioned question as well. it'll b great help