# Create Debian package without bin dir inside project

Tags: debian, debian-packaging

deb package with structure (project (bin(source)) DEBIAN(control)) can be created

But want to create deb package without bin directory instead there r multiple directories and source file inside the project, can't change files location.

Can i make modification so it wouldn't look for the bin folder instead check all files and directories for deb package creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes.

there's plenty of online and offline documentation for creating Debian packages (and your question is broad enough to indicate that you just need to re-read the docs)

E.g. `apt-get install packaging-tutorial maint-guide`
(The `maint-guide` aka "Debian New Maintainer's Guide" is available in about a dozen languages, in case you don't like the English version)

Or online: https://wiki.debian.org/HowToPackageForDebian